# Como transformar um projeto Pyqt5 em um executável?

Tags: linux, windows, pyqt, pyqt-5

Eu gostaria de saber qual seria o melhor caminho para converter uma aplicação `Pyqt5` para uma aplicação executável.

- Existe alguma meio de "compilar" uma aplicação em Pyqt5?
- Existe alguma forma de criar um instalador para uma aplicação Pyqt5?

Especificamente, tenho como alvo o Windows, mas gostaria também de saber como seria possível criar uma aplicação Pyqt5 para Linux.

Comment: Ô do negativo! Tem como explicar aí o que está errado?

Comment: Voce vai precisar do interpretador python e as dependencias compiladas especificamente para Windows/Linux. Recomendo dar uma olhada nessa ferramenta que me parece capaz de empacotar tudo em um unico executavel. http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse [artigo](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Deploying_PyQt_Applications), tem várias opções para fazer o que está querendo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de começar preciso citar detalhes importantes, várias respostas como sendo PyInstaller a solução, mas isso é só parte da resolução, o que é preciso que as pessoas entendam é que PyInstaller não resolve magicamente tudo, isso porque Linux não é um sistema operacional, Linux é um núcleo, existem muitos sistemas operacionais **"baseados"** no núcleo Linux (GNU/Linux), ou seja existem diferentes distribuições e a maioria (se não quase todas) não tem compatibilidade.

Sim meu povo, um programa compilado em Debian não vai funcionar em CentOS, apesar de ser uma comunidade *open-source* grande ainda sim cada grupo pensa de sua maneira, cada distro segue um caminho, e talvez essa divisão na comunidade seja o mal deles (mas é especulação de minha parte).

Fora que mesmo sendo escrito em Python um programa criado em PyInstaller vai embarcar o Python da versão do Linux especifica para o executável, vou dar um exemplo, usei o PyInstaller em um Ubuntu com um Python que esta instalado no sistema também, o que vai ocorrer é que o Pyinstaller vai copiar o executável python do sistema (ou do virtualenv) para o "pacote" gerado pelo PyInstaller junto com uma versão executável que ele vai gerar, então se tentar rodar isso em um CentOS ou Debian provavelmente não irá funcionar (mesmo que debian e ubuntu sejam "parentes").

### PyQt5 e o deploy básico (por enquanto em Windows apenas)

Muito bem, vou primeiramente falar de alguns detalhes básico, vou explicar em *Windows* por enquanto porque ainda estou preparando o ambiente no meu CentOS e no meu Debian para poder colocar detalhes de maneira precisa.

Eu recomendo muito que faça a instalação via `pip`, pois assim terá os pacotes maior facilidade de controlar os pacotes e até de instalar eles, mas antes de qualquer coisa eu também recomendo **muito que use virtualenv**, mais detalhes em:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Isto porque os pacotes usados para uma versão do PyQt assim como do PyInstaller podem mudar, atualizar e outros situações assim, que podem fazer com que em um update acidental você perca um projeto mais antigo, então isolar uma versão do PyQt e outros pacotes para um projeto deste tipo pode ser interessante, assim se mover de máquina, atualizar o teu Python global, não afetará o teu projeto.

Para evitar rodeios vou a explicação básica com **passo a passo**:

1. Crie a pasta do projeto, vamos chama-la de `exemplo`, pode fazer via `explore.exe` clicando com o direito do mouse/rato "nova pasta" ou via `cmd` com o o comando `md exemplo`)
2. Abra o prompt de comando (se não estiver aberto) e navegue até a pasta aonde criará o projeto, no caso é a pasta `exemplo`:

   ```
    cd c:\Foo\Bar\exemplo
   ```

Isto é um exemplo, lógico que vai digitar um caminho real, absoluto ou relativo.

1. Digite o comando:

   python -m venv .env

> O `.env` é uma pasta, gerada pelo `-m venv`, nela vai conter uma cópia do Python atual que você usa

1. Agora é necessário iniciar o virtual env, para isso ainda no cmd e na pasta `exemplo` digite isto:

   ```
    .env\scripts\activate.bat
   ```
2. Estando no ambiente virtual agora você deve instalar os pacotes necessários, no caso eu tentei instalar os mais atualizados, mas houve algum problema, talvez seja algum conflito/bug com o Python 3.6 e 3.7, para isso eu instalei versões especificas que funcionaram bem (claro que você pode atualizar isso conforme desejar), os comandos (pacotes necessários são):

   ```
    pip install PyQt5==5.9.2
    pip install PyInstaller==3.3.1
   ```
3. Pronto o ambiente esta criado, para testar o PyQt5 crie um arquivo chamado `main.py` e coloque este conteúdo nele:

   ```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(800, 600)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```
4. Após salvar o documento execute-o para testar:

   ```
    python main.py
   ```

Deve ser exibida uma janela vazia (pois é apenas um exemplo inicial)

1. Agora o momento do `deploy` tão esperado, usando o PyInstaller execute:

   ```
    pyinstaller --windowed main.py
   ```

Isto irá gerar o executável, no exemplo ele ficará na pasta `c:/Foo/Bar/dist/main`, a pasta toda é necessário para funcionar.

### Em ambientes baseados em Linux e Mac OSX

Em breve irei colocar exemplos como CentOS e Debian e se possível Mac, no momento estou um pouco impossibilitado, devido a ser algo muito trabalhoso, mas já adianto que para gera um pacote de instalação talvez tenha que usar o que é explicado nos seguintes links (irei adicionar mais conforme puder):

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package/pt
- https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

Não sei se o pyinstaller resolve esta parte, creio que ele gere apenas o arquivo executável (*executável stand-alone*)

---

### Criando um instalador

Infelizmente isso não é fácil, você pode criar na mão, com PyInstaller mesmo, ou outro executável que instale, claro que isso tudo vai ficar meio solto, então as soluções práticas são:

- Criar um **SFX/SEA** (self-extracting archive) com WinRar ou 7zip
- Instalar **Inno Setup**: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

O *Inno Setup* é interessante, prometo criar um pequeno "tutorial" aqui na resposta mesmo de como configurar o `.ini` dele, colocando ícone e até talvez "scripts" que serão executados no momento da instalação (para eventualmente de maneira customizada preparar o sistema operacional para algo necessário).

Answer (score 2):

A [Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Deploying_PyQt_Applications) do Python recomenda algumas ferramentas que podem fazer isso. Em especial tem duas que atendem ao que quer:

#### [fman build system](https://build-system.fman.io/)

Permite empacotar aplicações executáveis em *PyQt5* e criar instalador para as plataformas *Windows*, *Linux* e *MacOS*.

A documentação oficial no [github](https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial) provê um tutorial sobre a geração dos instaladores.

#### [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Assim como o *fma* o *pyinstaller* provê um ambiente para empacotar programas *Python* em aplicações, para as plataformas *Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX.*

A [documentação oficial](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/) detalha bem a criação do instalador.

Answer (score 1):

Eu usei o Pyinstaller para poder criar a estrutura executável do programa.

Os passos utilizados foram:

- Instalei o Python 3.5, versão 32 bits
- Usei o Virtual Env, através do comando `python -m venv venv`.
- Ativei o `env\Scripts\activate.ps1` (no meu caso, usei Windows 10).
- Instalei o `Pyqt5.9.2` e o `PyInstaller 3.3.1` pelo `pip`.
- Rodei o comando `pyinstaller --paths .\venv\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin main.py`. No meu caso, `main.py` é o script principal do meu aplicativo.

Isso cuidou de criar a estrutura do executável, com todas as dependências.

Eu usei essa resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682416/3096922) para efetuar esses passos e funcionou.

<sub>Vou tentar melhorar a resposta para efetuar a criação do instalador</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Eu também uso Qt5 com Python, mas no PySide 2.
Você pode compilar (empacotar) para executável usando o Pyintaller.
Porém o Pyintaller no momento só suporta até o Python 3.6.
Não recomendo outro, pois o Pyintaller é o mais usado e o mais popular.
Por isso ou você usa o Python 3.6 ou espera um pouco sair o suporte ao Python 3.7, pois o suporte esta a caminho.
Aqui esta um print do PySide2 com Qt 5.11.1
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No meu caso, rodou redondinho com `PyQt5==5.9.2` e  `PyInstaller==3.3.1`, de acordo com os requirimentos desse repositório: [fbs-tutorial](https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial/blob/master/requirements.txt)

Comment: Certo, mas qual versão do Python? 3.7? Porque pelo que eu sei, o Pyinstaller ainda não suporta Python 3.7, apenas até o 3.6.

Comment: Lá no repositório fala Python 3.5

Comment: Python 3.5 já esta bem antigo né.

Comment: Interessante. Eu falando da mesma ferramenta e ganho -2 pela resposta .. Lembrei por que faz tempo que deixei de contribuir no Stack em português.

Comment: Dei um positivo pra você, sua resposta esta correta, o PyInstaller.

Comment: As pessoas aqui esperam que você ajude com os passos ou código específico, de preferência que compile para poder só fazer copy e paste.

Answer (score -3):

```
pyinstaller main.py --clean --onefile --windowed --noconsole --add-data "WebBrowserInterop.x64.dll;./" --add-data "WebBrowserInterop.x86.dll;./" --add-data "Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView.dll;./" --add-data "Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView.LICENSE.md;./" --icon "icon.ico"
```